# find elements in list that fullfill condition WHICH needs the previous element

Tags: python, list

So I want to test if a list contains a element which fullfills a condition for which the previous element is needed. E.g.:

```
liste = [1,3,5,2,6,4,7,1,3,5,2,3,4,7]
```

And now I want to test for two numbers if they occur consecutive in the list (e.g. `find(liste, 3, 4)` would give out TRUE if 3 comes directly before 4 in the array liste, otherwise FALSE)

What gives me problems is that a number occurs multiple times in the array. And I need to test it for every occurence. Any ideas?

FYI: I have implemented it in javascript but now want it in python. In javascript I use:

```
!!liste.find((element, idx) => idx > 0 && liste[idx-1] == 3 && element == 4)
```

But I have trouble translating that into pyhton...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) + [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
liste = [1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 4, 7, 1, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 7]


def find(lst, first, second):
    return any((first, second) == pair for pair in zip(lst, lst[1:]))

print(find(liste, 3, 4))
```

**Output**

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
zip(liste, liste[1:])
```

will give you a pairwise iterator on every item and its predecessor.

Comment: I think you mean `zip(liste, liste[1:])`